# Unable to create a dynamic byte[] to process data received through Async TCP socket response

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, tcpclient

In my C# code I am receiving a `byte[1024]` from a DLL through TCP link.
Code I did for this I am attaching below.

The workflow is

1. An asynchronous packet gets received at tcp port into a byte array,
   which then gets copied to a different array for processing.
2. This copied array then gets processed according to received packet
   size(each message could be of different size one behind another).
3. While in the meantime async method received another data which
   should get appended to array used for processing packet.

Problem coming is being method as asynchronous data arriving at TCP port is getting appended anytime to the processing buffer array which many times throws exceptions while its size is getting referred during `Copy` methods.
I am unable to block this async call as after processing one packet.

```cs
// Method to process recieved packet  
_message.OnRecieve(message);
```

UI is getting updated and on user's action again the send and receive methods getting called where receive buffer array gets overwritten with new data.

Sharing piece of code:

```cs
public class Client
{
    // State object for receiving data from remote device.
    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];   
    }

    public static T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
    {
        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack = 2)]
    public struct MessageHeader
    {
        public int size;
    }

    private static byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 10];

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 3)
            {
                //if data does not contain any data to process 
                if (data.Length == 0)
                    Array.Copy(state.buffer, 0, data, 0, bytesRead);
                else
                {
                    //resize data array according to data it contains+data arrived
                    Array.Resize(ref data, data.Length + bytesRead);
                    //if data array contains data and state.buffer arrives with new data 
                    Array.Copy(state.buffer, 0, data, data.Length, bytesRead);
                }

                // process all data that exist in data array  
                while (data.Length > 2)
                {
                    byte[] headerbyte = new byte[2];

                    //read two byes of data contains message length in format IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder
                    Array.Copy(data, 0, headerbyte, 0, 2);

                    //reverse bytes in headerbyte
                    Array.Reverse(headerbyte);

                    Array.Copy(headerbyte, 0, data, 1, 1);
                    Array.Copy(headerbyte, 1, data, 0, 1);

                    //getting recieved message size from structure
                    MessageHeader header = ByteArrayToStructure<MessageHeader>(data);

                    int packetSize = header.size;

                    //if data contains within data array is partial packet
                    if (data.Length < packetSize)
                    {
                        // Get the rest of the data.
                        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        byte[] message = new byte[packetSize];
                        byte[] remainingData = new byte[data.Length - packetSize];

                        //copy message data to process into message array
                        Array.Copy(data, 0, message, 0, packetSize);
                        //copy remainng data into a temp array
                        Array.Copy(data, packetSize, remainingData, 0, data.Length - packetSize);

                        //Method to process recieved packet
                        _message.OnRecieve(message);

                        //Removing processed Message from data array by resizing it to of size remaingin data and copying content into it
                        Array.Resize(ref data, remainingData.Length);
                        Array.Copy(remainingData, 0, data, 0, remainingData.Length);
                    }
                }
                // Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // Create call back for next incoming packet
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol. There is no logical connection between "packets" written by one peer, and "packets" read by the other. You need to read length (or header) information from the socket, and then read the rest of the data ("packet") once you know how much is there.

Comment: @glenebob: Thanks for reply, but since I am using  client.EndReceive(ar) method to read data to a buffer, I am able to read data only after this method executed completely, also problem still will remain the same as being an asynchronous call i can't process data one by one.